# Does the Power Cable Double as an Antenna?

Tags: power

Today I had a weird experience with my HP Pavilion laptop. I've recently started an online course where I have to watch training modules online. At some point I wanted to take my laptop into another room so I disconnected the power cable. There was an odd static that followed this and it distorted the sound and I had to plug it back.

What is the meaning of this?

Comment: No; The power cable does not serve as an antenna.

Comment: A power cord can act as an antenna.  That's why they sometimes have ferrite cores (aka donut) on the cord.   I've had an audio amplifiers pick up a local AM radio station with just the power cord.  But those audio amplifiers have a linear power supply.  You laptop has a switched-mode power supply, and the AM radio signal would be filtered out, so that it's impossible for playback through the speakers.

Comment: But, not in laptops. Laptops are designed not to use the power cord as an antenna.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the power cable does not act as an antenna, and would not make a good one.

An educated guess is that the laptop was being grounded through the power supply but when you removed it the ground started floating and you had problems until you plugged it back in, grounding it again.

At a wild guess - Its conceivable that your microphone gain is high and/or your audio output is not grounded and you are amplifying white noise.